# Request new password form id

Tags: 7, forms, users

I want to know the Request New Password form id. (www.example.com/user/password).

I found out that the register form is "user_register_form" and tried same for password (user_password_form / user_pass_form / user_pass_reset) but nothing worked.

Hope you can help me! Thanks a lot!

Edit: If you could tell me the account form id in the same breathe, the answer would be simply awesome.

Comment: Are you in Drupal 6 or 7?

Comment: I'am using Drupal 7.

Comment: What is the path of the "account" page to which you refer (excluding your base_url)?

Comment: I found a solution for this, my panel module bugged and I couldn't find the form in the system page. After deleting and reinstallting the module it worked. 
Thanks for your help! The answer is useful for me beside the old problem discussed here. Do you have any experience with hook_form_alter on the profile form?

Comment: I probably do, what's the path of the form (excluding base_url)? Or are you referring to the user profile page itself?

Comment: The path is /user/*/edit.

Comment: The form id on that page is 'user_profile_form'.  If there is a bunch of stuff you need to do, you might better off opening a new question. Otherwise, I can answer quickly here. Or edit my existing answer.

Comment: Ok, I don't think its a very complicated issue. 
I need to get the plain text (!) password from the user_profile_form to insert it into another database, which use a different password hash algorithm. 
I'am sure I can achieve it with form_alter (sadly my already written module with user_update don't say me the password in clear text). I read that `$form_state['values']['pass']` can get me the password, but Drupal (and Devel) say me `values` don't exist. 
Hope you can help me, I appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: Edit: I'am using the method to verify E-Mail, so no theres no password entered in user_register_form.

Comment: The password is stored directly in the database in the users table and is hashed. I have no idea how to "un"-hash it.  That is a security issue and you should probably start another question for it.

Comment: Ok, done. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39967/rehash-drupal-7-passwords-into-sha1
Hope you can help me! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Note that print_r will be better in this case because to see the form he desires one must be logged out otherwise you'll get the password reset for the active user, which is different.

Leandros, try putting this in your theme's template.php and visiting user/password (not logged in)

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_pass':
        print '<pre>';print_r($form); print '</pre>';
      break; 
  }
}
```

It will give you an array of everything that's in there.  Then, say you wanted to change the text "Username or e-mail address" and the text on the submit button you could do this:

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_pass':
        //print '<pre>';print_r($form); print '</pre>';
        $form['name']['#title'] = 'Please type your username/email quickly.';
        $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = 'Email it to me!';
      break; 
  }
}
```

Comment: The access devel information permission also can give access to anonymous users to see the devel messages.

Comment: Absolutely @rooby , good call. Just don't forget to uncheck the permission or, better yet, uninstall Devel altogether, before you go to production. Could leave a big security hole there...

Answer (score 1):

install the [Devel](http://www.drupal.og/project/devel) module. Then implement [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and use dpm().

Then goto any page you want to see a form details on, you will see it in the System Messages block.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  dpm($form, '$form info for $form_id '.$form_id);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The form id is 'user_pass', but if I implement the form I get that error `Notice: Undefined index: user_pass in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 765 of /var/www/********/htdocs/includes/form.inc).
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'user_pass' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 800 of /var/www/********/htdocs/includes/form.inc).`

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to do to the `user_pass_form`. You shouldnt have to implement it yourself, you should be able to alter the form on the page with hook_form_alter() to add your own validation, form items, etc ...

Comment: I did a panal layout with pages and wanted to implement it in my panel layout.

Answer (score 0):

The IDs for these are:

- **User register:** `user_register_form`
- **User login:** `form_user_login`
- **User pass:** `user_pass`

I suggest you to use the [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7).

e.g. For change something in the User pass form:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_user_pass_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_user_pass_alter($form, &$form_state) {
  // Change text button.
  $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Send password');
}
```